# Content Won't Update PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, database

I have been working on small site admin but have run into an odd issue. I am able to pull content from the data base in but can't seem to get it to update and insert it into the data base. I would be thankful if anyone can look at this code and see why the content won't update. Here is the page code. I must be missing something.

```
    <?php include("../inc/approve-admin.php"); ?>
<?php include("../inc/connect.php"); ?>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY id");
?>
<?     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                    $id = $row['id'];
                                    $information = $row['information'];
                                    $link = $row['link'];
                                    $title = $row['title'];
                                   } 

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
$description = "Fashion Franchise";
$keywords = "Fashion Franchise";
$body = "home";
require ("../inc/header.php");
?>

<script src="../js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- for styling the form -->
<script src="../js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addResource").validate();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
});
</script>

    <body id="<?php echo htmlentities("$body") ?>">

    <div class="container_12">
    <!-- Nav -->
    <?php include("../inc/nav-admin.php"); ?>
    <!-- / Nav -->

    <div class="grid_12">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="grid_12">&nbsp;</div>

    <!-- Adimn List -->
    <?php include("../inc/admin-list.php"); ?>
    <!-- / Adimn List -->

    <div class="grid_7" id="white" style="min-height:400px;">

    <p style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">
    <?                  

    if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
        $information = $_POST['information'];
        $link = $_POST['link'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];

        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET
            title = '$title',
            information = '$information', 
            link = '$link'
            WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1 ;");

        if($query) {
            $message = $title . " has been updated";
        }else{
            $message = "an error occurred while updating this entry";

        }
    }   
?>  
    </p>

    <? if(isset($_POST['title'])) { ?>
            <div id="content_holder">
              <p style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">
              <strong><? echo $message; ?></strong><br/>
              <span class="error"><? if($error_message) { echo $error_message; } ?></span>
              Select a category on the left to continue editing</p>
            <!-- end content_holder -->
            </div>
       <? }else{ ?>


     <form action="inventory.php?id=<?=$id?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="addResource" id="addResource" method="post" class="cmxform">

    <table cellpadding="10px;" cellspacing="5" width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
    <tr><td colspan="2"><h1>Edit Inventory Resources</h1></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td width="50%">
    <span class="formTitle">General Information</span><br/>
    <label>*Title</label><br/>
    <input id="title" name="title" class="required" value="<?=$title?>"/>
    </td>
    <td width="50%"><br/>
    <label>*Dropbox Link</label><br/>
    <input id="link" name="link" class="required" value="<?=$link?>"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <hr/>
    </td>   
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2">
    <textarea style="width: 510px; height: 400px; font-size: 12px;" id="information" name="information"><?=$information?></textarea>
    </td></tr>

        <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <hr/>
    </td>   
    </tr>


    <tr align="right"><td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Update Inventory Resources" class="submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.php" class="cancel">Cancel</a><br/><br/>
    </td></tr>
         </form>

        </table>


    </div>



<?php include("../inc/footer.php"); ?>

    <!-- / Container_12 -->
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
  <?php

    mysql_close();
    ?>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors (either the error message you defined or a native PHP/Mysql error) or does it say it works but nothing happens?

Comment: Also, your code is open to SQL Injection. You need to escape your variables to before putting them into the query.

Comment: The error message does fire

Comment: I would love any direction on escaping variables.

Comment: Re: escaping variables, the best way would be to look into using PDO isntead of mysql_* functions (google search PHP PDO), which allows parameterized queries. If you must use the current methods, you can use mysql_real_escape_string() around your strings, and be sure to cast your integers and booleans appropriately (e.g. `$integer_value = (int) $_POST['integer_value'];`)

Comment: Please add the output of mysql_error() to your error message and provide it here (update your question).

Comment: It appears that $id is either not defined or else is defined to the id of the last retrieved entry at the top of the page. In either case, that is probably your issue. You should be passing the ID into the form through a hidden input and then use that in your query.

Comment: Here is my Error Message:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a quote mark in your text:

> 's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
>   took a galle

Fastest solution is to escape everything before inserting into the table:

```
    $information_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['information']);
    $link_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
    $title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $id = (int)$id;   // Cast this as an integer to also make it safe

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET
        title = '$title_to_insert',
        information = '$information_to_insert', 
        link = '$link_to_insert'
        WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1 ;");
```

Then, later where you display, you also need to make safe for display:

```
    $information_to_display = htmlentities($_POST['information']);
    $link_to_display = htmlentities($_POST['link']);
    $title_to_display = htmlentities($_POST['title']);
```

BUT - check out PDO Prepared statements as advised in comments. Start now before you're forced to change all your code over in a few years.

Comment: That's what I am talking about!